# JQuery getJSON() makes request header url duplicated

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm getting a duplicated value in my request url when i try and run the below ajax function:

```
var url = "localhost/travel/home/getPrevApplicantData";
$.getJSON(url, {group_id : "1"})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log( "JSON Data: " + json.address_telephone );
})
.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
});
```

The function is inside an onclick event, and I get the following header when the ajax function is run:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/travel/home/addApplicantVi_pageload/localhost/travel/home/getPrevApplicantData?group_id=1&_=1387835412861
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

I'm using CodeIgniter as my PHP framework, and the controller method that issues the call to get the data from the models method is in the Home controller and named getPrevApplicantData.

I don't know why the url is being sent back like this, but I'm unable to get any result for my done function using ajax. How do I make it so that I can specify the right url without having it being appended to the current one?

I'm also getting an error in Devtools which points to this line in JQuery:

```
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
```

And my fail function returns:

```
Request Failed: parsererror, SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
```

But I'm failing to realise where the problem is. If you need more info please let me know, would love to solve this problem.

Comment: the url is relative to the current location, if you want an absolute path add the `http://` or if you need to go up a level `../getPrevApplicantData`

Comment: @Goose Thanks that fixed it :P. Please write this as an answer and I'll gladly accept it. I'm however still stuck with the xhr.send error which I think is a cross domain type error?

Comment: is it failing when you send the data, or is it failing during the `.done` function? If it gets to `.done`, what is the type of the `data` object?

Comment: @Goose I'm getting the data back just fine, but the error just keeps coming up upon sending the data in Devtools

Comment: well it may be returning something, but that something might not be well-formed JSON data, which would trigger your fail. It would be helpful to see a response if possible.

Comment: If you don't want to post your data you can always test it with a validation service like http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Goose sorry my data is ok in terms of format. it's returned as [{"address_telephone":"11 someroad avenue-high point-nc-27262-3369934483"}]

Comment: @Goose Sorry if I haven't made myself clear. The .fail function does not run, I'm just curious as to why devtools pauses on this line in JQuery: xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null ); (I'm interpreting this as an error). Otherwise the fix works. please excuse my pessimism :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url is relative to the current location, if you want an absolute path add the `http://` or if you need to go up a level `../getPrevApplicantData`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `url` variable is wrong; it should probably be `/travel/home/getPrevApplicantData`

URLs starting with / are absolute, starting from domain/server root. URLs without / are considered to be relative to current document, which is why it appends your specified URL to your current document URL.

As far as the additional URL paramater `_=1387835412861` is concerned, this is added by jQuery to prevent browsers from caching the response from your queries. This can be controlled by the `cache` setting in $.ajax() as described at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/